# How to set the color of aUIButton?

Tags: ios, uibutton

Any idea how to set background color of a UIButton?

I tried to use

```
self.sendButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: You can do it programmatically: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5553081/194707

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a custom button. You can set an image as the background or define UIColor.

Take a look at these links:

[Iphone UIButton background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591281/iphone-uibutton-background-color)

[Is it even possible to change a UIButtons background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808888/is-it-even-possible-to-change-a-uibuttons-background-color)